# Ctrl + F5 causes page to jump around but F5 does not

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

I am getting this strange behavior in Firefox browser in one of my client's website pages.

When I clear cache and refresh, or, refresh the page using Ctrl+F5 the page's formatting gets distorted.

Immediately after this if I press F5 (and not Ctrl+F5) the page loads correctly.

I tried to troubleshoot and reset the browser as per the links [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-firefox-issues-using-safe-mode) and [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/reset-preferences-fix-problems).

I also searched through the net and various forums of firefox but could not get this resolved.

The Firefox version is 41 but I think the issue is with all the versions.

This is working fine is Chrome.

The URL with the issue is [here](http://www.infochoice.com.au/calculators/lump-sum-calculator/).

The following screenshot would also help understand my question.

[image: Screenshot here]

Please help!

Comment: I tested it with Edge browser and everything is fine.

Comment: Firefox 43 seems ok ... but ... have you checked the console and seen all the errors on that page? Hard to believe you've made that a public facing **website** with so many errors

Comment: I spoke too soon ... it's intermittent, but has nothing to do with f5 vs ctrl-f5 ... sometimes (rarely) f5 causes bad page load, sometimes (also rarely) ctrl-f5 causes bad page load ... perhaps it has to do with some javascript that isn't being run because of the bad code, and depending on the timing, something important isn't being run in some cases .... `An unbalanced tree was written using document.write() causing data from the network to be reparsed.` - seriously? `document.write` ? No wonder you're having problems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `<div id="page">` whose width is set to 911px in CSS. 
Then you have a script which changes its width to 100% on `$(document).ready()` event.

Now, the ready event cannot fire until all synchronous JavaScript files, and the document itself is loaded. On a primed cache, the JavaScript files will load faster hence the ready event will fire quicker, setting the page width to 100% before you notice it.

However, on an empty cache, the JavaScript files will take longer time to load. The browser might render some part of the page before the ready event is fired. In fact, the second screenshot shows a "Transferring data from..." status which (most likely) means that the page is not loaded yet.

Solution:

You want to prevent the page from jumping around when it is loaded and you need to set the page width via JavaScript and you cannot wait until document ready/page load. One solution is to inline the JavaScript code that changes the page width. First define these CSS classes:

```
#page { width: 911px; }
#fullwidth + #page { width: 100%; }
```

Then insert few lines of inline JavaScript:

```
<script>
if (mustBeFullWidth) {
    document.write('<div id="fullwidth"></div>');
}
</script>
<div id="page">
    <!-- content -->
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Salman, thanks for the lead. I do not have a designer in my team, a major drawback. However, I tried adding a window.setTimeout so that i can delay the execution of the script but to no avail. Can you give me some directions?

Comment: Hi Salman, thank you very much for this. Will implement your solution and provide you with my findings. Upvoted.